# How do you sort unanswered questions with [tag] by newest first?

Tags: discussion, tags, search

I don't want to answer a question that 2 years old when the OP hasn't been seen in 1 year 364 days. That's an extreme case but typically when I look at unanswered questions for $tag they are unsorted, or at least appear to be by the naked eye. Is there a way to sort them newest first? I tried a tried a meager url hack, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me I use:

In the search dialog:

```
 answers:0 [tag]
```

or my favorite that HopelessN00b helped me with:

```
 answers:0 intags:mine
```

And THEN click the `newest` tab

---

This assumes by "unanswered" you literally mean 0 answers so far, if you want "unanswered" meaning that the OP hasn't accepted an answer yet you would use:

```
hasaccepted:no [tag]
```

or

```
hasaccepted:no intags:mine
```

and then click the `newest` tab

Comment: I don't think you can search by [tag] and then sort by newest as well as unanswered, it's one or the other.

Comment: I believe you are correct Iain.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exist directly within the search facility. The best I could come up with is

> [tag] created:YYYY-MM-DD answers:N

so something like

> [[linux] created:2014-03-07 answers:0](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D%20created:2014-03-07%20answers:0)

Will get you close but remember that SE's definition of unanswered means that a question has no *upvoted* answers so this will be different from the unanswered tab.